# How to get index of selectd class or input in groupe of them

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have write following code

```
 <div class="right">
    <span>Attach your file here</span>
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
    <input type="file" class="attachfile" name="fileData2">
 </div>
```

now i want the index of the input type="file" only i have tried tried jquery code but it return index from "1" because it consider span on '0' index how i can get only index of the type="file" from '0'. if any one has solution then inform me

Comment: `$(<group of element>).index(<selected element>)` or `$(<selected element>).index(<group of elements>)` Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("elementselector").parent().children('input[type=file]').index($("elementselector"));
```

Find all the type of elements to you want(like i have got all the childerns that are of type file). Then pass the selector to index method to get its index in matched elements.

Comment: It would help to explain the different parts of your expression for future readers.